# Centrar horizontalmente etiquetas label e img

Tags: html, css

**Hola**.

Lo que quiero hacer es que dos textos que están uno a cada lado de una imagen se mantengan alineados y todo esto se centre en la página.

Algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que llevo de código es lo siguiente:

**HTML**

```
                <div class="header">
                    <label class="header-text">Texto 1</label>
                    <img class="header-img" src="../resources/img/all/header-img-2.PNG" alt="IMG" />
                    <label class="header-text">Texto 2</label>
                </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 300px;
    background: red;
    
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    
    vertical-align: central;
}
.header-text {
    padding: 0 30px;
    font-size: 48px;
    color: #FFF;
}
.header-img {
    width: 250px; height: 250px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 5px solid #FFF;
}
```

Y actualmente así es como luce:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Es decir, ya logré centrar los textos con la imagen, pero todo ese contenido no lo puedo centrar en la página.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comentarios respecto a tu código:

- El *posicionamiento absoluto* que das no parece ser necesario dado el resultado que esperas
- El `top` y `left` tampoco deberían estar si quitamos el posicionamiento al elemento
- El `header` es un elemento de bloque, por tanto ocupará el ancho máximo de su etiqueta contenedora, bajo esa idea entonces el `width` que otorgas lo veo innecesario
- Mas que darle un alto definido al `header` (*lo cual en ciertos casos puede no convenir tanto*), yo le daría un margen de separación con respecto de sus elementos internos y de esa manera evitar que la imagen en su parte superior e inferior quede pegada al `header`
- Ya que estás usando *flexbox*, entonces puedes mover y separar a los elementos horizontalmente con `justify-content` y darle un valor tal vez de `space-around`

Entonces el código pudiera quedar así:

```html
<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .header {
    align-items: center;
    background: red;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .header-img {
    background-color: white; 
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px; 
  }
</style>
<div class="header">
  <label class="header-text">Texto 1</label>
  <img class="header-img" src="" />
  <label class="header-text">Texto 2</label>
</div>
```